# UPC Code Problems

Tags: java, checksum

I have been trying to find out why my output is not what it is supposed to be. The Samples given are

> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 036000291453 Check digit
>   should be: 2 Check digit is: 3 UPC is not valid
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 036000291452 Check digit
>   should be: 2 Check digit is: 2 UPC is valid
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 014633149077 Check digit
>   should be: 4 Check digit is: 7 UPC is not valid
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 014633149074 Check digit
>   should be: 4 Check digit is: 4 UPC is valid
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 0853911765722 ERROR! UPC
>   MUST have exactly 12 digits
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): 085391176572 Check digit
>   should be: 2 Check digit is: 2 UPC is valid
>
> Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit):  Goodbye!

The algorithm of getting the that output is this From left to right, add the digits in the odd-numbered positions (starting the count from 1) and multiply the result by 3.
From left to right, add the digits in the even-numbered positions to the total computed in step 1
Take the result from step 2 and compute the remainder when divided by 10 (result modulo 10).  If the remainder is not zero, subtract this remainder from 10 to get the check digit.  If the remainder is zero, then the check digit should be 0.

```
    String str1 = validinput(in);
    int odd1 = odd(str1);
    int even1 = even(str1);
    int f = (odd1+even1)%10;
    if(f != 0){
        f = 10-f;
    }
    System.out.println(odd1);
    System.out.println(even1);

    System.out.println("Check digit should be: "+f);
    System.out.println("Check digit is: "+str1.charAt(11));
    int y = Character.getNumericValue(str1.charAt(11));
    if (f == y){
        System.out.println("UPC is valid");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("UPC is not valid");
    }
}


private static String validinput(Scanner inScanner){

    System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
    String str = inScanner.nextLine();


    while(str.length() != 12){
        if (str.length() == 0){
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("ERROR! UPC MUST have exactly 12 digits");

        System.out.print("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
        str = inScanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return str;
}


private static int odd(String input){
    int i = 1;
    char ch;
    int sumOdd = 0;
    while (i < 11){
        ch = input.charAt(i);
        int x = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        sumOdd = x +sumOdd;
        i += 2;
    }
    int Mx3=sumOdd*3;
    return Mx3;
}


private static int even(String input){
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    int sumEven = 0;
    while (i < 11){
        ch = input.charAt(i);
        int x = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        sumEven = x +sumEven;
        i += 2;
    }

    return sumEven;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`charAt()` uses null-based indexes, but the instruction wants you to use 1-based indexes. So, in odd() start with i = 0. And in even() start with i = 1.

Secondly, you use `Character.getNumericValue(ch)` to get the unicode codepoint value of the character, but the instructions ask you to use the digit value. So, use `Integer.parseInt(ch.ToString())`  instead.

```
private static int odd(String input){
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    int sumOdd = 0;
    while (i < 11){
        ch = input.charAt(i);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(ch.ToString());
        sumOdd = x +sumOdd;
        i += 2;
    }
    int Mx3=sumOdd*3;
    return Mx3;
}


private static int even(String input){
    int i = 1;
    char ch;
    int sumEven = 0;
    while (i < 11){
        ch = input.charAt(i);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(ch.ToString());
        sumEven = x +sumEven;
        i += 2;
    }

    return sumEven;
 }
```

Code not tested

Comment: Thanks the problem was odd and even.